# Putting back online SQL AlwaysOn servers

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I got notification from System Administrators that they will upgrade some features on physical machines on which I have virtual machines (SharePoint and SQL servers).
SQL servers are in AlwaysOn mode, one primary and one secondary server.

Does it matter what SQL server they will put back online first or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Are the 2 nodes of your always on on different physical machines?

Comment: Yes, They are now on different physical machines.

Comment: Then I would do it as I answered, don't do them at the same time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I see it.

**Patch & upgrade the secondary/passive node first**

after this do a failover and check if everything is still working like it should.(this can mean waiting a week) If this is the case, then you can proceed with patching the other node.

If this is not the case you can fallback to your old node and revert the changes done on the other server, and get them back into sync.

I would definitely **not** patch both nodes at the same moment

**IMPORTANT: make sure you can take the hit on your logspace because during the downtime of your secondary node you will not have any log truncation**

Also make sure you have your Quorum settings configured properly, otherwise you might have some issues on your cluster level!

Comment: thank you very much on your answer. But, problem is that whole server room will be shutting down. So, both nodes will be down at some moment during the weekend. I do understand that secondary should go down first. But when power gets back, what server/node should be back online first?

Comment: The first one online will be the one who will become the active node. Is there no kind of control you can have on when which server will go down?

Comment: I can only suggest what node should be shut down first. But they are shutting all servers down at the same day due to some UPS upgrade.

Comment: Ok, then do the passive one first, then when it is back up, do a manual failover. then do the other one.This way you have more control & you can make sure your downtime is kept to a minimum

Comment: Ok, thank you very much on your help and time!